# IndexOutOfBoundsException preventative measure not working [Java]

Tags: java, arraylist

Code here works well at dealing two cards at a time which is the primary setup for card game I am making. The issue I am having is that I am having trouble catching the program and getting it to stop before reaching the end of the deck. Essentially what should happen is that when the deck is set to 52 cards, it will draw two cards at a time each time enter is pressed. Once it is down to the last two cards (which I expected to be represented by `j == 1`) an if statement would catch it and run a separate set of code that prints the last two cards and then says "You are out of cards". For some reason, no matter how I try to set the if statement, it never evaluates and the program reaches the end of the deck and gives the error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at Game.main(Game.java:65)`

Not sure how I can get it to catch the size of the list before it is too late.

```
ArrayList<String> deckList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(deck));//Changing Array with card contents into an ArrayList


    while (deckComplete == false) {         //While loop for dealing cards


        for (int j = deckList.size(); j > 0; j--) {


           // System.out.println("Hit enter to be dealt a card!");    
            String readString = scanner.nextLine(); //Set variable "readString" to user input

            if (readString.equals("")) {        //If user input equals "enter"...

                Collections.shuffle(deckList, new Random());

                if (j == 1) {   //If program gets to last card...
                       deckComplete = true; //Set desk complete to true

                       System.out.println(deckList.get(0));
                       System.out.println(deckList.get(1));//Print last card
                        System.out.println("You are out of cards!"); //Print "You are out of cards"
                       break; //Stop loop
                   }    
                        System.out.println(deckList.get(0)); //Print first card. Error code points here. 
                        deckList.remove(0); //Remove card
                        System.out.println(deckList.get(0)); //Print next card
                        deckList.remove(0); //remove card

               }



       }
```

Comment: Which line corresponds to "at Game.main(Game.java:65)"?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have updated the comments to show where it is. Is is the second to last system out print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `j = deckList.size()` but j only decrements by 1 each iteration, while you're actually taking 2 cards each time. j needs to decrement by 2:

```
ArrayList<String> deckList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(deck));//Changing Array with card contents into an ArrayList


while (deckComplete == false) {         //While loop for dealing cards


    for (int j = deckList.size()-1; j > 0; j-=2) {


       // System.out.println("Hit enter to be dealt a card!");    
        String readString = scanner.nextLine(); //Set variable "readString" to user input

        if (readString.equals("")) {        //If user input equals "enter"...

            Collections.shuffle(deckList, new Random());

            if (j == 1) {   //If program gets to last card...
                   deckComplete = true; //Set desk complete to true

                   System.out.println(deckList.get(0));
                   System.out.println(deckList.get(1));//Print last card
                    System.out.println("You are out of cards!"); //Print "You are out of cards"
                   break; //Stop loop
               }    
                    System.out.println(deckList.get(0)); //Print first card
                    deckList.remove(0); //Remove card
                    System.out.println(deckList.get(0)); //Print next card
                    deckList.remove(0); //remove card

           }



   }
```

Comment: Ah such a silly mistake! I was editing the code to preform a different function and didn't think to change that increment. That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) although, as the other poster mentioned before removing his answer, you will want to either change `deckList.size()` to `deckList.size()-1` or change `if (j == 1)` to `if (j == 2)` since decrementing by 2 will cause j to skip 1 in the current setup.